# Как переназначить главную страницу в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу, переназначить главную страницу

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'advanced' => 'advanced/backend/controllers/calculator/index'
        ],
    ],
```

Rules не срабатывают. Как можно переопределить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    'urlManager' => [
        ...
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'calculator/index', // Контроллер/экшн
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите чтобы все запросы на страницу site.ru или site.ru/ переходили на конкретный котроллер, то пропишите такой путь

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'calculator/index', // Контроллер/экшн
    ],
],
```

и еще есть роутер по умолчанию, можно изменить его и не трогать правила выше

```
'defaultRoute' => 'main/index',
```